# C# с com порта приходит сообщение с обнулёнными битами

Tags: c#, usb, com-порт, com-port

Отправляю byte массив на com port. 
Формат сообщения -{ 0x01, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x45 } Формат ответа должен быть-{ 0x02, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x41 }
0x02 выводится нормально, но остальные выводятся как 00.В формате ASCII выводит правильно.В чём может быть проблема?
Код:

```
byte[] readCrad = { 0x01, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x44 };
byte[] chakCard = { 0x01, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x45 };
SerialPort port;

string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

Console.WriteLine("Выберите порт:");

// выводим список портов
for (int i = 0; i < ports.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("[" + i.ToString() + "] " + ports[i].ToString());
}
port = new SerialPort();

int num = 0;

try
{
    // настройки порта
    port.PortName = ports[num];
    port.BaudRate = 9600;
    port.DataBits = 8;
    port.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
    port.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
    port.ReadTimeout = 1000;
    port.WriteTimeout = 1000;
    port.Open();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: невозможно открыть порт:" + e.ToString());
    Console.ReadKey();
    return;
}
string result = string.Join(" ", chakCard.Select(d => d.ToString("X2")));
Console.WriteLine(result);
port.Write(chakCard,0,chakCard.Length);
byte[] resp = new byte[6];
int response = port.Read(resp, 0, resp.Length);
string hexString = "";
for (int i = 0; i < resp.Length; i++)
{
    hexString += resp[i].ToString("X2")+" ";
}
Console.WriteLine(hexString);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: ком порт не успевает передавать данные, скорее всего.

Comment: response  - чему равно?

Comment: Показывает,что 1

Comment: А как это можно исправить?

Comment: Тогда попробуйте добавить цикл с "ожиданием" ещё одного. это вы получили первый байт.

Comment: Как исправить - 1. Добавить ожидание, и собирать данные по байту в один кусок. 2. Перепрошить ваш контроллер что б присылал пачку байт, а не по одной штуке.

Comment: Читаете байт - складываете, доспустим в List. Ждёте секунду - читаете следующий - складываете в List. И так пока 6 штук не прочтёте.

Comment: работает, но только возникает при каждом 2 разе  Exaption:  время ожидания операции истекло

Answer (score 1):

Исправил таким образом:

```
        response = port.Read(resp, 0, 1);
        response = port.Read(resp, 1, 1);
        response = port.Read(resp, 2, 1);
        response = port.Read(resp, 3, 1);
        response = port.Read(resp, 4, 1);
        response = port.Read(resp, 5, 1);
```